# Error 1046:Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant

Tags: actionscript, compiler-errors, flash-cs6, compile-time-constant

I'm trying to make a interactive flash video in CS6 for a class I am taking. I briefly talked with the professor about this and he could not figure out the issue either. The weird thing is it says the errors are on lines 2 and 3.  When I remove the code on those lines it **still** says the error is on those lines. Take a look at my AS and tell me what you think.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.*;

public class Essay1 extends MovieClip{

public function Essay1() {

    mc_Gas.visible = false;
    mc_Drive.visible = false;
    mc_Outside.visible = false;
    mc_DriveZoom.visible = false;
    mc_Dash.visible = false;

    mc_Start.btn_Start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, gotoWindow);
    mc_Drive.btn_Drive.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, gotoZoom);
}
public function gotoWindow(MouseEvent):void{
    mc_Start.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
public function gotoZoom(MouseEvent):void{
    mc_DriveZoom.visible = true;
    mc_DriveZoom.mc_Car3.mc_HeadDown.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

}
```

Here's the error message:

F:\WDMD201\Essay\Essay1.as, Line 2  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: mc_Dash.

F:\WDMD201\Essay\Essay1.as, Line 2  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: mc_Drive.

F:\WDMD201\Essay\Essay1.as, Line 3  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: mc_Gas.

F:\WDMD201\Essay\Essay1.as, Line 3  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: mc_Start.

F:\WDMD201\Essay\Essay1.as, Line 4  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: mc_Outside.

F:\WDMD201\Essay\Essay1.as, Line 5  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: mc_DriveZoom.

Comment: What type was not found? Can you paste the full error message?

Comment: BTW, you also have another error your code. `gotoWindow(MouseEvent)` should become `gotoWindow(event:MouseEvent)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to access unknown properties. To access them, your need to declare properties matching the instance names on the stage. Declare all the properties `mc_Dash`, `mc_Drive`, and so on, as member variables :

```
public class Essay1 extends MovieClip {

    public var mc_Dash:MovieClip;

    public function Essay1 {
    ....
```

Comment: This actually wasn't the problem.  It turned out that the class name could not be the same as the instance name.