# Flash, actionscript 3.0: How to link playback buttons to movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, video

I am getting the following error.

`/Volumes/PCC-2014/CAS-175/module_7/, Line 1, Column 163    1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: video.`

I have named the instances, set up linkage and named the class.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAnimation);

function playAnimation(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
video.play();
}

stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playAnimation_2);

function playAnimation_2(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
video.stop();
}
```

Comment: Is `video` a FLVPlayback component?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423596/error-1046type-was-not-found-or-was-not-a-compile-time-constant